# How to change header view background color if I still want to use the standard headerview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, background-color

One way to do so is to use

```
tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

However, that means I have to provide my own `headerView`.

I want the normal standard `headerView`.

I just want the `background color` to change.

How do I do so?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout method from UITableViewDelegate Protocol:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Here you get the header view (view) that is going to be displayed.

Maybe something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```